# Flash - AJAX call

Tags: ajax, flash

I want to call a web page from Flash and use the data returned from it (either in plain text or XML).  I see with the NetConnection you can connect to a web service, but I just want to call a plain old web page.

It seems like I managed to do this a while back, but for the life of me, I can't find the answer on the web.  Does anyone know what the function / code is to call a web page in Flash and get the data back?

Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All you need to do is use a URLLoader.

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest= new URLRequest("http://example.com/page/");
_urlLoader = new URLLoader();
_urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLDataLoaded, false, 0, true);
_urlLoader.load(urlRequest);


function onXMLDataLoaded(evt:Event):void {      
    var xml = new XML(_urlLoader.data);
}
```

Comment: I'm an idiot.  I was looking at this far more complicated that I needed to.

Comment: Congrats, you have now 2013 reps, happy new year 2013 :)

Comment: I want to use current-browser cookies too for making this request, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you're using AS3 then you'll want to use the URLLoader class. One common mistake using URLLoader is that you need to pass it an instance of URLRequest like so:

```
var loader:URLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
```

Note that you use the URLRequest object to specify and GET/POST parameters you want to send so in that case you want to build the URLRequest separately rather than inline.

Comment: I want to use current-browser cookies too for making this request, how can I do that ?