# How can I get data from a php form instantly and write datas to a xml file used by a flash banner

Tags: php, xml, flash, banner

I have a flash banner working with xml and I want a control page for it. For example, when I change banner width from control page also banner change at the same time and same page without refresh. So that occur a preview for flash banner. PHP,HTML and banner available. But how can I get data from form instantly

Answer (score 0):

if "instantly" means without refreshing the page, you need to search for **AJAX**.

here's a starting point for you:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

or, directly from flash:

[Flash - AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045986/flash-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-write the  code with AJAX, modify all size-related properties for the swf. The script will monitor the form, and onChange (not onSubmit), read the values, remove the previous  code and write a new one. I don't think that simply changing the values of the previous object will work on the fly.