# How to load variables from php to my flash file?

Tags: php, flash, variables

First I would like to thank you all for your kindness and help over the years.

I'm trying to make my swf file read variables from a php file.
But it doesn't work at all:

Could anyone help me please? I've googled many hours, but still can not find an answer.

I have added this to my swf/fla project:

```
myData = new LoadVars();
myData.onLoad = function(success) {
    if (success) {
       var money = this.myvar;
    } else {
        trace("Error loading!");
    }

};
myData.load("http://localhost/varstoflash.php");
```

This is the content of the php file:

```
<?php

$money = "20000";
print "&myvar=$money";

?>
```

But it doesn't work.

Could anyone help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a previous question asked about using a Flash AJAX Call that might help

[Flash - AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045986/flash-ajax-call)